# followHyperlink to open a named pdf and go to a specific cell

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Working in access db form frm_Rest which has a couple of controls txt_Shop and txt_Stat with a command button btn_PDF.

Whenever a user makes a credit entry for file CR-Acct the name will appear in *txt_Shop* and the credit amount will show in txt_Stat.

The btn_PDF alerts user to submit a pdf_CR (Sumbission of pdf_CR is Optional). If user decides to submit a pdf_CR, and btn_PDF is clicked a popup asks if user wants to create a pdf_CR request, if **YES**, then OPEN related **active *txt_Shop** pdf_CR from the **stored** location.

The address of the stored location is as follows: "T:\YTD-Statements\July Reports\CR-Statements\pdf_CR" and these are some of the files in pdf_CR that are available to be OPENED CR-Finance, CR-Bank, CR-Home, CR-Acct.

I need btn_PDF to auto-open the related file currently being processed in **txt_Shop** such as CR_Bank.

I have tried using the two followHyperlinks below. The first one gets me to the folder without opening the desired filename, and the second one pops out and error msg "Cannot Open the specified file". I need to be able to get whatever file (CR-Finance, CR-Bank, CR-Home, CR-Acct) that is in txt_Shop control.

Private Sub btn_PDF()Click

Dim LoanRef As String

Dim x As Long

LoanRef = Me.txt_Shop.Value

FollowHyperlink "T:\YTD-Statements\July Reports\CR-Statements\pdf CR"

FollowHyperlink "T:\YTD-Statements\July Reports\CR-Statements\pdf CR" &CR_Bank.pdf"

Please Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is your question? See [ask]

Comment: Inv123 is a declared string variaable and its value is never set.so it is empty. If you want the literal text "Inv123" then don't concatenate it as a variable, just include it with the file path string between quotes. If you want whatever is value of txtstore, then reference that control in the concatenation.